# How can I get an alphabetic input to match another alphabetic input in length?

Tags: python, repeat

I need to get a user-input keyword to be the same length as a user-input message, for example:

```
keyword = "gcse"  # the keyword input
message = "python" # the message input
newkeywordshouldbe = "gcsegc"
```

This seems simple, but I have been unable to figure out how to accomplish it.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the modulo operation (`%`) and array indexing.

```
keyword = 'gcse'
message = 'python'
n, m = len(keyword), len(message)
print ''.join( [ keyword[ i % n ]  for i in range(m) ] )
```

The following interactive Python session (with `keyword`, `message`, `n`, and `m` already declared and initialized) explains:

```
>>> range(m)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [i % n for i in range(m)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1]
>>> [keyword[i % n] for i in range(m)]
['g', 's', 'c', 'e', 'g', 's']
```

Comment: I really enjoyed quickly working through how this works: it is like mpcabd's solution minus an import (which is great). Examining `[keyword[i % n] for i in range(m)]` (which yields `['g', 's', 'c', 'e', 'g', 's']`) and thinking about the modulo results should trigger a light-bulb moment for anyone else who is initially unclear. :P

Comment: There is also another solution which uses the modulo: `newkeyword = keyword * (len(message) / len(keyword)) + keyword[:len(message) % len(keyword)]` :)

Comment: @mpcabd: I actually like that solution best of all because it remains a one-liner that requires no imports but makes the 3-way logic I explained pretty apparent.  Looping/cycling through/over `keywords`'s characters maps to that 3-way logic too of course; but it is nicer to see it more clearly called out -- I think.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to use the [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) function like this:

```
from itertools import cycle

keyword = "gcse"
message = "python"
iterator = cycle(keyword)

newkeywordshouldbe = ''.join(iterator.next() for i in range(len(message)))
```

Comment: you could also just do `for _ in message`

Comment: Nice.  This is what I meant by a more Pythonic possibility.  Thanks!

Comment: If we're importing from itertools anyway, there's `''.join(islice(cycle(keyword), len(message)))`; but in any case, we can use `next(iterator)` instead of `iterator.next()` to be more forward-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
keyword = "gcse"
message = "python"
newkeywordshouldbe = "gcsegc"

keywordLen = len(keyword)
messageLen = len(message)

if keywordLen == messageLen:
    newkeyword = keyword
elif keywordLen > messageLen:
    newkeyword = keyword[:messageLen]
elif keywordLen < messageLen:
    # Use keyword in its entirety as many times as possible to match
    # message's length; then match the rest of message's length with
    # as many of keyword's characters as needed.
    newkeyword = ''.join(keyword * (messageLen / keywordLen)) + \
        keyword[:messageLen - keywordLen]

print newkeyword
```

You can run the code above in a related [Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/F29PjW).

Also, you could squeeze more from less and make the solution more [Pythonic](http://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html) (e.g. like [mpcabd's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32529593/1810429)); but this *super clearly* conveys the logic given the three logical possibilities:

- `keyword` and `message` are the same length.
- `keyword` is shorter than `message`.
- `keyword` is longer than `message`.

Even employing a more Pythonic solution, it is important to understand the underlying logic of course.

Comment: thanks for that this helped me understand what was going on in the code

Comment: @ShahzaibShuzBari: You're welcome. Glad that you found my answer helpful; and now you have the reputation to upvote it accordingly if you like. ;)

Answer (score 0):

another way to approach it is:

```
import math
new_word = (math.ceil(len(message) / len(keyword)) * keyword)[:len(message)]
```

Comment: im not sure on how the import function works and also i have python 2.7 so i dont beleive they implemented it that early 
thanks for the help though